# How to synchronize between displaying the processor and running the loops in Delphi Parallel.For?

Tags: delphi

I have a `Parallel.For()` loop in my program as follows:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  n,m:integer;
  handle: THandle;
begin
  //BeforeTest;
  ProgressBar1.Position:=0;
  handle := Form1.Handle;
  n:=10;
  m:=100;
  SetLength(list,n*m);

  FTask := TTask.create(
    procedure
    var
      processed: integer; // shared counter
      total    : integer; // total number of items to be processed
    begin
      processed := 0;
      total:=n*m;
      TParallel.For(1,total,
        procedure(Index: Integer)
        var
          new: integer;
        begin
          new := TInterlocked.Increment(processed); // increment the shared counter
          if (new mod 10) = 0 then // update the progress bar every 10 processed items
            PostMessage(handle, WM_UPDATE_PROGRESS, Round(new / total * 100), 0);
          //Calculation procedure
          Calc(Index,Total);
        end);
    
      // Update the UI
      TThread.Queue(nil, AfterTest);
    end); // TTask.Run
  FTask.Start;
```

and in the `AfterTest()` procedure:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.AfterTest;
begin
  FTask:=nil;
  ShowMessage('Finished');
end;
```

When I run the program, the time to complete the ProgressBar and display the "Finished" message is different. The ProgressBar fills up sooner. How do I synchronize the time between "Finished" message and the ProgressBar?

Comment: Where does `AfterTest` get called the the code?

Comment: @R.Hoek `TThread.Queue(nil, AfterTest);`

Comment: Hamed, use thread.synchronize instead of Queue.

Comment: @whosrdaddy hmmm, seems I missed that, while reformatting the code... 

Comment: The progress bar is supposed to fill up sooner.  The natural order would be that the progress bar fills up and then the "Finished" message is displayed.  This seems to be what the code does.  What is the problem?  Also, you're setting `FTask` to `nil` before the task itself completes.  Is `FTask` an interface variable (ie: `ITask`?)

Comment: Hi Olivier,
Thank you for your answer,

Comment: It seems, like standard programs, the "Finished" message is not displayed as soon as the progressbar is completed. This happens a little earlier. I do not know where the problem is.

Comment: @Hamed How does it make sense that completion should happen before the last progress step is completed?  That seems obviously wrong to me.

Comment: The message is displayed at the correct time. But the progresbar completion is done sooner.

Comment: You probably want to update the progress bar after the calculation is completed, not before.

Comment: @J... If there is a reason to keep task variable (for cancellation) as field, then explicitly clearing that variable is prudent thing to do to avoid things lingering around more than needed and potentially creating reference cycles with captured variables.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes, but with `Queue` it's a race condition and with `Synchronize` guaranteed that the variable is cleared before the task completes.  If `FTask` is `ITask` this will call the destructor prematurely, no?  If it's `TTask` then the pattern seems wrong.

Comment: @Hamed Are you saying that you would like the final progress step and the "finished" message to be simultaneous?  If so then change your step scale to `90` from `100` and step the final 10% in `AfterTest`.  I would avoid `Synchronize` unless you absolutely need it.  `Queue` should always be preferred, imo, both for performance and simply due to not having to worry about deadlocks.

Comment: @J... you are right about Queue... but both Queue and Synchronize have their problems. in this particular scenario Synchronize seems fine because there is nothing that can deadlock.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes, it was a reason to prefer Queue generally, not in this instance.  The issue with Synchronize here is that if OP changes their code to use it then `AfterTest` will be called before the task completes.  Setting the interface variable to `nil` therein will destroy the task before it completes, yes?

Comment: @J... Additionally, I just realized that it TTask.Create is used and TTask.Run is preferred because it always returns interface. In any case FTask type must be interface ITask.

Comment: @J... No, there is another interface to task, so there will be no premature release.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel for starts many parallel instances of your proc, each updates the progress and after that calls Calc(), meaning it updates the progress before starting the work. That's why progress goes to the end way before the task ends. You should call Calc() first.